# Which is the best approach to access post save and post update event of a node ..?

Tags: 7, nodes

My requirement is to automatically create a PDF after **creating a new node** with its contents and replace the PDF with a new one while **updating the node**. Is there any way to access the event **post save**. My PDF creation code is ready but i dont know which **hook** to use. I need the **nid** too.

**Which hook sholud be used for post save and post update event..??**

Any help appreciated..

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [hook_node_insert()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) and [hook_node_update()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7) like in the following eample:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_insert().
 */
function MYMODULE_node_insert($node) {
  create_pdf($node->nid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through rules section of drupal.

Add the event - After saving a new content

Condition - Particular content type which you want your pdf to be created.

Action - Execute the custom php code.

As you have already finished the pdf creation code, this section will be easy.
Try it. May be this will help you.

Comment: i think code to create PDF wont work inside rules custom php code..rest all is right.

Comment: It would work @Abin, point is that you shouldn't ever use the PHP filter - it's a good practice and security black hole

Comment: I am creating pdf using dompdf library. Is it possible to call dompdf library from custom php...??